# Autofill Form Not Working

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

I want to make form, if i fill the first input (i.e 'rollnumber') ,  i want the rest of the input will filled automatically with data from mysql database (if the 'rollnumber' i filled is found in the database)
And if the 'rollnumber' not found in database it will say "Rollnumber not found".
How to achieve that goal?

The results with below code are:

1. The autofill not working, data won't show even i fill the right 'rollnumber'
2. the only thing that works is the #loading1, it show after i fill the data, but it won't hide back.

In case someone is kind enough to help me try my code to see what is wrong, here is the database (database name: login):

[login.sql](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2KTi0VIQ-Neb2RjRDlmQjAySTQ)

These are my codes so far:

**Form HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="rollnumber" id="rollnumber" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Roll Number" value="">
    <img src="ajax-loader.gif" id="loading1"></img>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="First name1" value="">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name" value="">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" value="">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="batch" id="batch" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Batch">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="lclass" id="lclass" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Class">
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#loading1").hide();
    $("#rollnumber").change(function()
    {
            $("#loading1").show();
            var id = $("#rollnumber").val();
            var data = 'one=' + id;
            $.ajax
            ({
                type: "POST",
                url: "checkrollnumber.php",
                data: data,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) 
                {
                    $("#loading1").hide();
                    if (data) 
                    {
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { //for each user in the json response
                            $("#fname").val(data[i].fname);
                            $("#lname").val(data[i].lname);
                            $("#email").val(data[i].email);
                            $("#phone").val(data[i].phone);
                            $("#batch").val(data[i].batch);
                            $("#lclass").val(data[i].lclass);
                        } // for

                    } // if
                } // success
            }); // ajax
    });
});
```

**checkrollnumber.php:**

```
require_once "conn.php";
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
if(isset($_POST['one'])){
$json = array();
$id =  trim($_POST['one']);
$query = "SELECT fname, lname, email, phone, batch, lclass FROM users WHERE rollnum = ?";
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($nFname, $nLname, $nEmail, $nPhone, $nBatch, $nLclass);
while ($stmt->fetch()){
   $roll=array('fname'=>$nFname,'lname'=>$nLname,'email'=>$nEmail,'phone'=>$nPhone,'batch'=>$nBatch,'lclass'=>$nLclass);
    array_push($json,$roll);
}
echo json_encode($json, true);

 }
```

**conn.php (connection)**

```
$DB_host = "localhost";
$DB_user = "root";
$DB_pass = "";
$DB_name = "login";


try
{
    $DB_con = new PDO("mysql:host={$DB_host};dbname={$DB_name}",$DB_user,$DB_pass);
    $DB_con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: looks your heading the right direction, does your browser developer console show any errors?

Comment: so far the browser dev console not showing any errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return false if the `rollnumber` isn't in the database, so to do that you could check if the array is empty or not using `count()`, replace the following line :

```
echo json_encode($json, true);
```

By :

```
if( count($json) == 0){
     echo json_encode("false", true);
}else{
    echo json_encode($json, true);
}
```

Then is your JS code you should add a condition to show `"Rollnumber not found"` like :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#loading1").hide();

  $("#rollnumber").on('input', function(){
    $("#loading1").show();
    var id = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "checkrollnumber.php",
      data: {one: id},
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data) 
      {
        if (data == 'false') 
        {
            alert("Rollnumber not found");
        }else{
          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { //for each user in the json response
            $("#fname").val(data[i].fname);
            $("#lname").val(data[i].lname);
            $("#email").val(data[i].email);
            $("#phone").val(data[i].phone);
            $("#batch").val(data[i].batch);
            $("#lclass").val(data[i].lclass);
          } // for

        } // if

        $("#loading1").hide();
      } // success
    }); // ajax
  });
});
```

**NOTE :** The `data` parameter should be sent like `data: {one: id}`.
I suggest also the use of `input` as event since it's more efficient when you track the use inputs :

```
$("#rollnumber").on('input', function(){
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: hi, thanks for the suggestion, still, autofill not work even i input the right 'rollnumber', the data not show. The 'false' condition you suggested not show any message. the only thing that works is the #loading1, it show when i input the rollnumber, but it not hide back. what is possibly wrong here?

Comment: i updated the question and included database file above, in case you want to try it
thank you..

Comment: I modified my code from some references in this site, and it is works perfectly as i want, even better. I choose ur answer because it helps me a lot with the false condition. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Don't declare variable similar to keyword, as in your case you declared variable `data`, which is confusing with `data` keyword in `ajax`.

```
var data = 'one=' + id;
```

Also, change below line of code

```
 data: data,
```

to

```
 data: {one : $("#rollnumber").val() },
```

Comment: thank you but still now working
i updated the info and included database file above, in case you want to try it..

Comment: @Angga could you try debugging ? `alert(data)` and see what data you are getting as response ?